# Getting textarea value in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

Iam using Tinymce Editor for creating some content.I used textarea for getting tinymce editor.

For edting i have used this code

```
<textarea id="page_content_id" name="page_content"><?php echo $page_content;?></textarea>
```

So the saved value will be in tiny mce editor.If i add something to the editor how i can get the values in javascript using

```
document.getElementById("page_content_id").value
```

This wont give the new value.How i can get the  entire value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<textarea id="page_content_id" name="page_content" cols="50" rows="15">This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE.</textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ShowHTML(mceId)
{
    alert( tinyMCE.get(mceId).getContent() );
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="ShowHTML" onclick="ShowHTML('page_content_id');">
```

or use `.getHTML();`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value in javascript by using the following

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

If you have multiple editors open at the same time, use

```
tinyMCE.get(idOfEditor).getContent();
```